# how to get current longtitude and latitude in fragments using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, location

Is there a way to get the location in fragments using Kotlin, I have researched for the way to get locations but they all did it in the activity. Is there a way to get the location in the fragment? Using Kotlin?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320952/how-to-get-location-in-fragment)? It is in written in Java, but you could convert it to Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do things in activity or fragments it's the same.

Just move from onCreate of MainActivity to onActivityCreated of fragment.

Of course permission has to be checked in the activity, because they require context, and would be weird do it in the fragment, but all the code and UI stuff can be done in the fragment itself.

Better explanation.

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

1. **In Main activity ask permission**

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

   ```
   // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
           Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
       != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
           arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
           MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION)

   } else {

       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
               .commitNow()
         }
      }
   }
   ```

If permission where already grant replace the fragment that will show data, if not ask permission.

2. **Permission Result**

   ```
   if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == 
         PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
               supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                   .commitNow()
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }
   ```

   If permission are given do the same thing, instantiate fragment.

**FRAGMENT**

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity!!.applicationContext)

    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                lat_view.text = location.latitude.toString()
            }

            if (location != null) {
                long_view.text = location.longitude.toString()
            }
        }
}
```

Fragment will use FusedLocationProviderClient to get location.
If you want more information about it look here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

How to import packages

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

As you can see in

```
.lastLocation
```

I get the latitude and longitude

**NOTE**: I put null check because as you will notice if you do not do that there is the chance that value are null

Comment: Why don't you add some code to make your answer more simpler.

Comment: Ok i will make more well explaned.

Comment: If you still have any doubts ask clarification  :)

Comment: Hi first of all, thank you for your patience for helping me out!!!! I appreciate that. But I tried this code inside my fragment and it is not getting the locations. I have correct dependency...

Comment: oh never mind! i figured out thank you!!!! its that i mistyped something!

Comment: and just to make sure is MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION an int? and what value did u set it to ?

Comment: private const val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION = 1

I put it as top level const